# Can't fetch Childs by name using their parent id in a query

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate, jpa

I have this structure, where the parent have a OneToMany relation with the child and the child has a ManyToOne with the parent:

```
parent = {
   id: Long,
   children: [
        {
            childName: 'name1'
        },
        {
            childName: 'name2'
        }
    ]   
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is fetching the child objects in a list using a query where I pass a like (name) and I pass the id of the parent. The problem is that when I try to add the parent id, it always returns me an empty array.

In my case, this code works, it returns me all the Childs of the database with the name like x:

```
@Query("select o from Child o where lower(o.name) like lower(concat('%', :name, '%'))")
    List<Child> getChilds(@Param("name")String name);
```

However, if I try to add the Parent id, it returns me empty Arrays always:

```
@Query("select o from Child o where o.Parent.id = :parentId and lower(o.name) like lower(concat('%', :name, '%') ) ")
    List<Child> getChilds(@Param("parentId") Long parentId, @Param("name")String name);
```

This one doesn't work neither:

```
@Query("select o from Child o join o.parent c where c.id = :parentId and lower(o.name) like lower(concat('%', :name, '%'))")
    List<Child> getChilds(@Param("name")String name, @Param("parentId") Long parentId);
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first Query should be working if you are using valid IDs. Is it possible to retrieve the entire Parent by its ID? Also is there any reason to have a space between the equal signs and the double points? Also why are there spaces at the end of the query?

Comment: I'm going to post a new question as I found that my problem is related to my relations... thanks anyway @SirHawrk